# Sweep through all machine learning classifiers?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, weka

I'm using Weka to perform classification, clustering, and some regression on a few large data sets. I'm currently trying out all the classifiers (decision tree, SVM, naive bayes, etc.).

Is there a way (in Weka or other machine learning toolkit) to sweep through all the available classifier algorithms to find the one that produces the best cross-validated accuracy or other metric?

I'd like to find the best clustering algorithm, too, for my other clustering problem; perhaps finding the lowest sum-of-squared-error?

Comment: Have you already tried out the WEKA-Experimenter? It allows to use many classifiers and compare the outcome with statistical tests.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't that some kind of overfitting, too? Trying tons of classifiers, and choosing the best?

Also note that preprocessing is usually very important, and different classifiers may need different preprocessing; and each classifier has in turn a dozen or so parameters...

Same for clustering, **don't choose a clustering algorithm by some metric**. Because if you choose e.g. "lowest sum-of-squares", k-means *will* win. Not because it is better. But because it is more *overfit* to your evaluation method: k-means optimizes the sum-of-squares. The results may be crap on other metrics, but on SSQ, they are by design a local optimum.

Data mining is not something you can automate to a push-button level.

It's a skill that requires experience on how to preprocess, choose algorithms, adjust parameters *and* evaluate the actual outcome. Otherwise, you'd have some software on the market where you just feed your data and get the optimal classifier out.

Comment: Yes, I realize that data mining is fine art where most of the work is in the feature engineering. But I would just like to know if there is a way to automate the classifier-selection process. I've been running Weka by hand and inspecting the results after each cross-validation for the last several months and would like to make it a bit easier.

Comment: Also, if I'm doing cross-validation, why wouldn't I choose the classifier with the highest n-fold cross-validated accuracy? That's the standard practice,right?

Comment: @Anony-Mousee: "Data mining is not something you can automate to a push-button level." I know you're just saying that to protect your job.

Comment: Yeah, and all statisticians only want to secure their jobs, too; that is why they insist on proper null-hypothesis testing and such. And medical doctors, that insist on double-blind studies, they also just want to protect their jobs. It's actually the same thing.